# How to prevent viewing ajax post variable values using console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am generating a random string using javascript and send it to the server using ajax post method. Is there any way to prevent that user view that post variables using Browser Console?

Comment: NO, since js is client-side there is no way - you can encrypt it, but since that happens on client-side to, its uselesss too because the user can decrypt it the same way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If some information is available to the browser, then it is also available to the user of that browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you could encrypt it somehow to make it harder to decipher if that is your goal.